# PHP - Print objects to console/log for a back-end function

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

I'm fairly new to PHP, so forgive me if there's an easy answer to this. I've searched for any similar questions in stackoverflow, but couldn't find any help.

I'm working on an existing php-based application, and I simply need to be able to print the contents of objects and arrays to either a log or console for debugging. The catch is that the function isn't directly called by the client, but rather pulls MySQL data, modifies it, and returns the data. This means options like Chrome Logger (https://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger) and using console.log() in javascript do not show up in the console.

The application I'm working for has a simple logging function, but it only accepts strings. I am unable to modify the log function, and as such am having trouble printing objects and arrays of which I have no idea what the contents are.

Does anyone have any advice as to how to proceed in this matter?

In particular, I'm trying to find the results of the MySQL query, so if there's a workaround to obtain that data, that would would work as well.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you not have anywhere that you could output a `print_r()` of your array/object? Or a way you could check to see if you're logged in to a particular account (assuming you're storing that info in `$_SESSION` or something) before just running a `print_r()` out to the page?

Comment: Is the script being called using AJAX? You can use the Network tab of Developer Tools to see the raw AJAX response, which will include any debugging messages the script prints.

Comment: @Barmar The script is using AJAX, the problem was that since the query was on the server's side, rather than the client's side, the entire query is hidden tot he client and the Network tab gave no results

Comment: @ZachButtram it looks like it's not using `$_SESSION`, but it looks like I could have used that to extract the information and move it to a printable place. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php or Monolog, but that only solves half of the question.  You will also need to serialize the object to something that can be represented in a log.  You could use php serialize, json encoide or the __toString method to generate that result.  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php for magic methods that maybe useful.

Comment: ^This is the best answer I could find -  I used the error log and used `_TJson()` to print the result. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "This is the best answer I could find" - I can see that you are new here. Please note that accepting an answer makes it clear to others who might have the same question in future.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the log to a file on the server itself.

file_put_contents('log.txt', $thelog, FILE_APPEND);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: I will upvote this because it will work, even though it doens't answer the OP's question. I imagine that he wants to see JS & PHP output intermingled.

Comment: Thanks Mawg for the vote. But what the original question asked for was a "back-end trace of the PHP script". I was just sharing what I have done sometimes. Its not the perfect solution but a quick one.

Comment: And a solution which I have used myself :-)  before I discovered Chrome Logger - give it a try; I am sure that you will like it

Answer (score 1):

I am using chromelog to console log any var in chrome s dev tools. simple & fast debug anything in PHP.

[chrome-logger chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-logger/noaneddfkdjfnfdakjjmocngnfkfehhd)

[chrome-logger main](https://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger)

Answer (score 0):

I think `error_log(print_r($object, true));` is a good and simple option. It works because the second parameter `true` returns the value instead of printing it directly and `error_log()` prints to the terminal.